# How to convert Keras model which uses Mask Rcnn to create masked image on custom object detection to CoreML model for use in iOS app?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, coreml

I've developed a Keras model which is trained on a custom image dataset and it works pretty well with object detection and masking of the detected object when an input image is sent. I want to export this model to CoreML (.mlmodel) so that I can embed it in my iOS app directly.

I also have my trained model using Tensorflow with Mask RCNN. So any help in converting the Keras or Tensorflow model to CoreML. I have already tried and successfully converted Tensorflow model to CoreML but that model doesn't support Mask RCNN.

I am specifically looking for help in converting the model which supports Mask RCNN to CoreML.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out https://github.com/edouardlp/Mask-RCNN-CoreML ? This guy is basically using matterport's implementation of mask rcnn with core ml.